# Change the orientation or font type using WordCloud instead the color?

Tags: python

I doing a wordcloud in python, and i need that the words change to horizontal or vertical orientation acoording any condition. For example, if a word was written by a male it would be horizontal. Instead, if a word was written by a female it would be vertical. I have changed the color, but I would like change the position or the font type.  Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.